# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on one GET request

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, get, mean-stack

working with a MEAN Stack and I have three GET requests for the same URL/Route. One is to get a generalised summary of long-term emotions, the other is to get a summary of emotions by dates entered, and lastly, a summary of emotions related to a user-entered tag associated with individual emotion entries.

My first GET request is throwing no issues but the second GET request throws an error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The error points to the following line:

> 48| each emotion in dateEmotions

Below is the relative code associated with the **error**:

**Jade**

```
each emotion in dateEmotions  
    .side-emotions-group
      .side-emotions-label
        p.emotion-left= emotion.emotionName
        p.pull-right(class= emotion.emotionLevel) &lpar;#{emotion.emotionLevel}&percnt;&rpar;
      .side-emotions-emotion.emotion-left
```

**GET Request**

```
module.exports.emotionsListByDates = function (req, res) {
  Emo.aggregate([
    { $match :
        { "date" : { $gte: ISODate("2018-04-09T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-04-13T00:00:00.000Z") } }
    }, { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "averageHappiness": {"$avg": "$happiness"},
        "averageSadness": {"$avg": "$sadness"},
        "averageAnger": {"$avg": "$anger"},
        "averageSurprise": {"$avg": "$surprise"},
        "averageContempt": {"$avg": "$contempt"},
        "averageDisgust": {"$avg": "$disgust"},
        "averageFear": {"$avg": "$fear"},
    }}
], function (e, docs) {
    if (e) {
        res.send(e);
    } else {
        res.render('dashboard', {
            title: "ReacTrack - User Dashboard",
            pageHeader: {
                title: "User Dashboard",
                strapline: "View your emotional data here."
            }, 
            dateEmotions: docs
        })
    }
  });
};
```

This question is already getting pretty long, but I have another GET Request pointed to that URL and it is not throwing any errors, and the only difference is that I am not matching the db records by date in that query. I can post the working code if need be.

**Edit**

After some experimenting, I am able to get each of the three routes working individually if I comment out the other two. It's when multiple routes pull in the multiple requests that causes issues. For example, here are the routes at present where the `ctrlDashboard.emotionsListByDates` is working:

```
// Dashboard Routes
//router.get(/dashboard', ctrlDashboard.emotionsListGeneralised);
router.get('/dashboard', ctrlDashboard.emotionsListByDates);
//router.get('/dashboard', ctrlDashboard.emotionsListByTag);
```

If I comment out two routes and leave one running, and comment out the respective `each emotion in emotions` `each emotion in dateEmotions` and `each emotion in tagEmotions` blocks in the Jade file and leave the correct one uncommented, then that route **will work**, it seems to be when I am firing multiple routes. Is this bad practice, or incorrect? Should all queries be in the one GET request if on the same URL?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't have documents matching your query, so `dateEmotions` stays undefined.

Comment: The query works in the Mongo shell in the terminal and outputs correct results.

Comment: though not related to error, I don't see you projecting `emotion.emotionName`, `emotion.emotionLevel` from mongo query. Are you sure you are pointing to right dashboard jade file?

Comment: Oh yes, that was back in the early days when I had some dummy data in another controller within app_server folder, the above request is in app_api. When changing those to     emotion.averageHappiness    for example, it still will not work.

Comment: Updated original post after some troubleshooting and experimentation. Still facing issues but a new kind of issue.

Comment: it sure is a problem to have the same URL routed to different controllers. How could the router decide which controller to use for an incoming request?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, new to routing and RESTful APIs but after some researching into the topic, I now understand the fault.

I assumed that the URL used in routing was the URL you wanted the data to populate...which it still kinda is, but I thought if I wanted to populate the dashboard page, I had to use that exact route and I did not realise I could post the data to different URL routes and take the data from those URLs to populate the one page.

Fixed by adding `/date` and `/tag` to those routes and using AJAX to perform those requests and populate the main page.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I'm using React+Redux+Fetch. So is it not a good practice dispatch more the one request in the same time and from the same page to a specific url?

I would know what causes that problem. I've found some discussions about it could be a mongoose issue.

My code:

```
MymongooObject.find(query_specifiers, function(err, data) { 
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  ...
 }
}
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined